# Tallying each character

Tags: java, arrays

NOTE: For array of counters, one for each UTF-16 character, tallies usage of each char.
For a program I am writing, im trying to tally each character in a specific word. Thus far, i have,

```
   public void tally(String word)   
   {  
      if ((word == null) || (word.length() == 0))
      return;

   (Insert here)

   }
```

For where I have "Insert here" is where i am trying to tally each character in a specific word. Does anyone know simple way of doing it?

Comment: please ,can you  give me example ?

Comment: I'd see if you can find some sort of `MultiSet` library

Answer (score 2):

- Create a map
- Start with the 1st char For each character, check if the character key exists in the map, if yes, increase the value of the key by one.
- If it doesn't exist, insert the character as key and value as one. when done, print the map.

Answer (score 0):

This look like homework so I'll give some brief pointers

- You can split a string into characters with [toCharArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)
- You can iterate over an array with [for each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
- You can store values in an [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: Can I construct it within my tally method or would it be smarter to create a new method?

Comment: I think it fits perfect inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void tally(String word)   
{  
      int count;
      if (word == null)
      {
           return count;
      }
      else
      {
           char[] ca;
           ca = word.toCharArray();
           for(int i = 0; i < ca.length; i++)
           {
                 count++;
           }
           return count;
      }
```

This will show you how many letters are in the word in total. I think, from this, you can do the rest.